# What's wrong with my switch mode power supply circuit?

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm using a TPS54383 dual output SMPS IC from TI, putting out 12V and 5V; at least in design. I created a schematic and board and had it sent out to OSHPark and soldered it all up today and only the 12V side works!? On the 5V output I'm only getting ~.82V.

Any ideas?

**Side note: I am using two different types of inductors, which I think may factor in here the 12V side uses: [12V inductor](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=SRR1210-470Mvirtualkey65210000virtualkey652-SRR1210-470M), 
and the 5V side uses: [5V inductor](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=SRN5020-220Mvirtualkey65210000virtualkey652-SRN5020-220M).

[image: design]

Also I've modeled up the circuit in TI TINA and simulated it and all appears well..see below:
[image: Ti Tina]
[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue! turns out On the 5V feedback resistor that goes to ground (R4) was not actually connected to ground! Ran a jumper and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

Since 0.8 is the reference voltage, I'd look closely at R3/R4. R3 have the wrong value (much too small or shorted by a solder bridge), or R4 may be wrong (much too large or cold solder joint).

Also, the feedback resistors on the +12 side are not correct. As shown, they should produce about a 5 volt output

Comment: Ill check the solder connection's when I can, but I've posted an edit in return about wrong values. Could you explain why I'm seeing correct voltages in the software?

Comment: Sorry, but my system does not show schematics well, and I misread the value for R7.